# How do i clone the content of a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, clone

I want to be able to clone all the tables in my mysql database into another database. But the catch here is that i don't want the cloned content to be static. I want it to update synchronously with the original database. is it possible in Mysql?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a [mysql slave](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html).

Comment: Can Mysql replication work with the mysql package that comes with phpmyadmin?

Comment: As far as I know phpmyadmin only acts as a front-end to a mysql server and you can't really use it to set up a server etc.